# iOS - Firestore Document Multiple Writes at same time

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have two users writing to the same document - it appears there are data integrity issues when the writes happen at the same time. What's the best way to handle this race condition with iOS Firestore?

Comment: Please add your code and explain how are you trying to write data simultaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make use of Firestore transactions. The transaction would fail whenever someone else has modified the document whilst you are writing. Read more about it here:

[Firestore Transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions)